# Why does my c++ code which I run in a Java SWT project, is paused?

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, user-interface

I have a c++ project for which I wanted to have a GUI. So, I decided to write the GUI in Java using SWT.

I'm first running Java with some inputs, then, it starts c++ project with `Process p = Runtime.exec(...)`. Every sec c++ project writes some string (path of some images) to an output file and java reads it and changes the images on the GUI accordingly.

The strange thing is, at one point Java code continue to run but c++ code get paused. When I stop Java code by killing GUI (that doesn't stop c++ project), it continues to run. When I run java code twice, at one point both stops, and I kill one of them the other continues.

Here is Java code that updates GUI.

```
public void open() throws InterruptedException {
    display = Display.getDefault();
    createContents();       

    shell.open();
    shell.layout();

    Thread updateThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(860);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("hi " + count);
                        count++;
                        refreshPanel();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };

    updateThread.setDaemon(true);
    updateThread.start();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, when c++ pauses count continues to be updated so I know that java is not paused.

It stops in different elements depending on `time` that I make java thread sleep by `Thread.sleep(value)`.

Note that my c++ code is runs two threads each of them writes to different files and each read by Java separately (for different purposes).

**EDIT**: When I run c++ in visual studio, it doesn't give any error or it is not paused.

My c++ code is basically as follows

```
int main(){
    string str1 = "sth1", str2 = "sth2";

    boost::thread bs_t = boost::thread( binary_search,str1,str2);
    boost::thread ls_t = boost::thread( linear_search,str1,str2);

    bs_t.join();
    ls_t.join();
}

void binary_search(string str1, string str2){
    if(some_condition)
        return;
    num_comp_bs++;
    ofstream myrec_file(project_dir+"\\bin_file.ini");

    boost::mutex _mtx;
    _mtx.lock();

    myrec_file << num_comp_bs << endl;
    myrec_file.close();

    _mtx.unlock();

    //here I do some I/O operations and some matrix calculations
    binary_search(str1, newstr1);
    binary_search(str1, newstr2);   
}

void linear_search(string str1, string str2){
    for(int i = 1 -->n){
        ofstream myrec_file(project_dir+"\\lin_file.ini");

        boost::mutex _mtx;
        _mtx.lock();
        myrec_file << num_element_passed << endl;
        myrec_file.close();
        _mtx.unlock();
        //here I do some I/O operations and some matrix calculations
    }
}
```

Note also that it doesn't give any error.

Any idea what may cause c++ to be paused? **Is it possible that windows is blocking c++ for some reason?**

Thanks in advance,

Comment: There are many C++ GUI libraries, why not use one of them? Even including the time to evaluate them and to learn to use of of them, you will most likely save time in the end, and especially effort.

Comment: Since you suspect the problem is in your C++ code, why did you only post the Java code? Can we see the C++ too?

Comment: You are right but I didn't have much time for learning them, so I decided on Java

Comment: @parrowdice: when I run the c++ program in visual studio it runs without any problem. But when I run from Java, it is paused for some reason.